# How to check Combination validation on field in cakephp

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I want to check two field combination validation for duplicate values. I have two fields name and area group.

```
$this->validate['Name'] = array(
        'notEmpty' => array(
            'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
            'message' => __('err_required', array(__('lbl_Name', true))), 
        ),
       'Name' => array(

            'rule' => array('uniqueClick', 'GroupID'),
            'message' => __(__('lbl_Combination', true)), 
        )
    );  

    $this->validate['GroupID'] = array(
        'notempty' => array(
            'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
            'allowEmpty' => true,
            'message' => __('err_required', array(__('lbl_GroupID', true))), 
        )
    );

    public function uniqueClick ($ip)
        {   
            $count = $this->find('count', array(
              'conditions' => array(
                  'Name' => $ip,
                  'GroupID' => $this->data[$this->alias]['GroupID'])
           ));
           return $count == 0;
        }
```

By this code it check combination in both add and update case ,i want to check combination in both case but by this code it check in edit case always after add. so please give me appropriate solution. reply fast.

Comment: you want to check if a value of name already exist in field groupId?

Comment: name and groupid both .(In a combination i want)means combination not exist in database

Comment: Check out [Validating uniqueness](http://www.dereuromark.de/2011/10/07/maximum-power-for-your-validation-rules/) or apply the core rule `unique` which allows multiple fields to be checked in combination. Your "notEmpty" rule is not the right approach IMO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a custom method use it in either in name or group and pass the value of name/group to custom function and and place the check in function:

```
$this->validate['Name'] = array(
    'notEmpty' => array(
        'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
        'message' => __('err_required', array(__('lbl_Name', true))), 
    )              
);  
 $this->validate['GroupID'] = array(
    'notempty' => array(
         'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
         'message' => __('err_required', array(__('lbl_GroupID', true))), 
     ),
    'duplicate' => array(
         'rule' => array('isDuplicate', $this->data['ModelName']['name']),
         'message' => __('err_required', array(__('lbl_GroupID', true))), 
     )
 );

public function isDuplicate($data, $name){
    // check here
}
```